# CoreData unique constraints: how to get field name on which constraint checking fails

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a simple table "Person" with two fields:
identity => String
name => String
This table have unique separated constraints: identity and name (not identity + name)

I try to insert into this table same data several times:

```
let names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
for i in 0..<3 {
    let p = Person() //NSManagedObject sublass
    p.identity = "1111"
    p.name = names[i]
    do { try p.managedObjectContext!.save() }
    catch let e as NSError { 
        if e.code == NSCocoaError.ManagedObjectConstraintMergeError.rawValue {
            print(e.userInfo["conflictList"]![0]!) 
        }
    }
}
```

I have in log:

> NSConstraintConflict (0x7ff12b84f600) for constraint (
>       identity
>   ): database:  (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000040000  ; data: ), conflictedObjects: (
>       " (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000140000  ; data: {\n    identity = 1111;\n    name = Name1;\n})"
>   )

How can I get field name on which constraint failes from userInfo  NSConstraintConflict (0x7ff12b84f600) for constraint ( **identity** ) ? Because in future I want to show messages with text like "Unique constraint check failed for field "identity" and "Unique constraint check failed for field "name" but while I cann't get field name from error it is not clear on which field check failed

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Nor `NSConstraintConflict` neither something like `NSConstraint` is documented. However, the constraint conflict knows the constraint:

> NSConstraintConflict (0x7ff12b84f600) for constraint ( ***identity*** ): database: (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000040000 ; data: ), conflictedObjects: ( " (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000140000 ; data: {\n identity = 1111;\n name = Name1;\n})" )

I would bet that you can get the constraint with

```
[conflict valueForKey:@"constraint"]
```

Look for the class of the result.

Comment: Thank you! I cann't suggest, that NSConstraint of type AnyObject contains string value with constraint name.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5, Xcode 13

Here's how I got the violation info:

```
} catch let e as CocoaError {
    let errorDictionary = e.errorUserInfo
    
    if let conflictList = errorDictionary[NSPersistentStoreSaveConflictsErrorKey] {
        let constraintConflicts = conflictList as! [NSConstraintConflict]
        
        for conflict in constraintConflicts {
            validationError = "Constraint violation(s) from: " + conflict.constraint.joined(separator: ", ")
            
            var duplicates: [String] = []
            for (propertyName, value) in conflict.constraintValues {
                duplicates.append("The \(propertyName) field should have a unique value. '\(value)' already exists.")
            }
            duplicatesError = duplicates.joined(separator: "\n")
        }
    }
} catch {
```

It prints out this, for example:
[image: example of print out]